# Get the size of an image in python

Tags: python, image

I need to get the size of an image, but to call an image I'm not using `img=open'rectangle.png'` instead I'm using `filename1 = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")])` 
but I get this error : 
`width, height = background.size 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

This is my code :

```
import tkFileDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename # Open dialog box
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy


filename1 = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")])
filename2 = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")])
img=cv2.imread(filename1,1)
background=cv2.imread(filename2,1)
offset = numpy.array((10,10))

background[offset[0]:offset[0]+img.shape[0],offset[1]:offset[1]+img.shape[1]]=img
width, height = background.size
print('width = ', width)
print('height = ',height)
cv2.imshow("Added Image", background)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Where are the docs that say a cv2 image has a `size` attrib that's a tuple of width and height? I suspect you might want `.width` and `.height` instead?

Comment: thank u for ur answer, but `.height` and `.width` didn't work, in my case, so I used `.shape` instead, and it worked perfectly.
Thank u agn